# How to set up compiled bindings in react native?

Tags: react-native, xaml, xamarin, data-binding, uwp

I'm new to React Native. In the UWP and Xamarin world, there's a concept of compiled bindings. I can create a text block that displays text from a variable in my view model. Like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Name}"/>
```

Since this is a compiled binding, when I try to compile my app, I get a build error if `ViewModel` does not contain a variable called `Name`.

How can I achieve this same compile-time check in React Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think anything similar is possible in React Native, as this is a XAML-specific functionality, which exists thanks to the fact that XAML/C# are inherently more compile-time safe than JavaScript. Also, even in XAML, `x:Bind` is more restrictive on what it can contain than the traditional `Binding`. In case of React Native, the bindings may contain virtually anything, so it would be very hard to resolve and check at compile-time.